# О добрости и добростях

Tags: синонимы, неологизмы

На сайте ТАСС (информационное агентство, http://tass.ru/dobrosti) в рубрикаторе есть позиция ДОБРОСТИ. Смысл раздела с такой шапкой в целом понятен, но как быть со звуком, рядом с которым другие, традиционные (*Политика*, *Экономика и бизнес*, *Общество*), выглядят свадебными генералами? Может быть найдётся разумная замена ему?

Answer (score 2):

Более официальным аналогом будет *прочее* (*прочие новости*) или "жизнь", но "добрости" привлекут больше трафика.

Словообразование здесь конечно не совсем русское, я без контекста сперва подумал о какой-то благотворительной акции, а не о добрых новостях, но, кто знает, может такое сращение основ на английский манер и приживётся.В целом слово неплохое, хотя крепко спящему во мне пуристу было бы приятнее увидеть какие-нибудь "добрые вести" или даже пускай "добровести"

Comment: Согласен полностью. А добрые новости на поверку — самые нормальные, — ну разве без криминала и критики. Я бы, пользуясь подсказкой, предложил: «Вот это жизнь».